# There is a conflict between double char pointers and strcpy()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

There is a strange address problem between the two double char pointers **lines and **splitted_line. After the strcpy some char* arguments disappear.

```c
Error readFile(FILE *file, ConfigValues *values)
{
  int filesize;
  char *buffer;
  size_t readchars;
  char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char*));
  char **splitted_line = malloc(sizeof(char*));
  char *buffer_line;
  char *buffer_token;
  int counter_lines = 0;
  int counter = 0; //TODO reneme
  int counter_argument = 0;
  int printf_counter = 0; //TODO to be deleten
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  filesize = ftell(file);
  rewind(file);
  buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * filesize);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    printf(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
    return OUT_OF_MEMORY;
  }  
  readchars = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), filesize, file);
  if (readchars != filesize)
  {
    printf("Reading error\n");
    return OTHER;
  }
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  //unfortunately you cant nest strtok, cuz of the NULL-param in the while!
  buffer_line = strtok(buffer, "\n");
  while (buffer_line != NULL)
  {
    lines = realloc(lines, (counter_lines + 1) * sizeof(*lines));

    lines[counter_lines] = (char*) realloc(lines[counter_lines],
        strlen(buffer_line) * sizeof(char*));
    printf("Stelle lines: %p, %p\n", lines, lines[counter_lines]);
    strcpy(lines[counter_lines], buffer_line);

    counter_lines++;
    buffer_line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }

  printf("counterlines: %d\n", counter_lines);
  while (printf_counter < counter_lines)
  {
    printf("%d:  %s\n", printf_counter, lines[printf_counter]);
    printf_counter++;
  }

  //TODO repair from down here

  while (counter < counter_lines)
  {
    printf("%d::  %s\n", counter, lines[counter]);
    buffer_token = strtok(lines[counter], " ");
    printf("Erstes argument der zeile: %s\n", lines[counter++]);
    while (buffer_token != NULL)
    {
      splitted_line = realloc(splitted_line,
          (counter_argument + 1) * sizeof(*splitted_line));
          printf("Stelle splitted lines: lines: %p, %p\n", splitted_line, lines[counter]);

      splitted_line[counter_argument] = (char*) realloc
          (splitted_line[counter_argument],
           strlen(buffer_token) * sizeof(char*));

      printf("%d, counter_argument: %d\n", strlen(buffer_token), counter_argument);
      strcpy(splitted_line[counter_argument], buffer_token); //the evil line!!!

      printf("gespeichert: %s\n", splitted_line[counter_argument]);

      counter_argument++;
      buffer_token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
      printf("test2: %s\n", buffer_token);
    }

    printf("-----------\n");

    counter_argument = 0;
    counter++;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

At the begin the char** lines:

0:  resolution 600 600
1:  pps              5
2:  nix
3:  wind        180 10
4:  gravitation    6.5

At the end:

0:  resolution
1:  pps              5
2:  nix
3:  wind        180 10
4:  gravitation

Need some help!

Answer (score 1):

With `buffer = (char)malloc(...)`, you are truncating the value of the dynamically allocated memory pointer from 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your platform) to 1 byte.

The code thereafter yields undefined behavior.

Comment: OP's above statement should be `buffer = malloc(...)`. Casting (correctly) as `buffer = (char*)malloc(...)` isn't even necessary in this case. Because the `void*` pointer is assigned to a `char*` type there is no confusion - unlike when you read a `char` using a `void*` pointer directly.

Comment: you're right, normally there is a char pointer. But somehow it got lost while copying the code. Please just ignore it.

Comment: *Please just ignore it.* do you mean there is still a fault or @barakmanos posted the solution?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think that OP will not get notified on this comment.